# Why making a Views page instead of Views block?

Tags: 7, views, blocks

In most of my projects views are displayed in a block instead of a page, eventhough it would be perfectly possible to make a views page in these cases.

The reasons why I do this:

- If the client wants to add some content on top of the view, he can
  easily do so by clicking the "edit" tab of the page the block is
  nested in. This is more accessible and easier to understand than
  creating/positioning blocks and setup their visibility, or even worse: use the header field feature of Views
  (which the client has no access to in normal cases).
- It's cleaner to manage the translated menu items to that page (taking in account that the menu items are manually grouped by language)
- If the client needs to, he can easily translate the page, and alter
  the visibility settings of the block so it would appear on the
  translated page as well. This makes more sense to clients than to fiddle
  around with translated alias urls.

Ofcourse, there must some downsides to this approach. One I believe is that it may increase the loading time of pages when there are a lot of other blocks in use (is that true?), but one should be able to counter this with the [Context module](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) I believe.

I'm bringing up this question to check this approach with other dev's to figure out if I should maintain this, or if I should reconsider it.

I live in Belgium, a country with two language communities (Dutch and French), so almost every project is multilingual, which is is also an important factor in the motivation above.

Comment: I believe there is no real answer for this. Blocks and pages are different things, differently managed, and each and every time site maintainer must decide for himself what does he need and what is he willing to trade. You pretty much described most important points of these decisions in your question, so... Is there anything objective to add? I honestly don't see.

Answer (score 1):

Blocks are appropriate to display piece of content but a Page is for displaying the whole content.

If you create a block of a View, using admin UI you can easily place it in any region (or panels) and reorder it but this option is not available if you use Page.

In Panels, if you use `Place In-Editor` option to build the pages (like the following image) pages will not be available. This is a very powerful tool in Drupal so if you don't use the appropriate structure you will miss it.

[image]

So as a result, by using blocks even a regular user can also easily change the structure of the site and no coding is necessary.

If you create a Page display of a View, to display it's result in some section of the page you must use `views_embed_view` (or similar ones) function to load that View. This function doesn't load the View title, widgets and ... .

You can use 30 variables to store 30 numbers but you can also use an array with 30 cells. Both approaches work but you should use the reasonable one. It is like your question. you can build your site using both display modes but you should use each one in it's right position.